# How to trigger language switcher

Tags: php

Hi i would like to set several languages on my site, a have good looking php script but i have a problem with trigger it, my knowledge of php is very poor

```
language.php

header ("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");


if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {

    $langID = $_GET['lang'];


    setcookie('lang', $langID, time()+(3600*24*365));
}

elseif (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {

    $langID = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} 

else {
    $langID = 'Pl';
}
```

and my index.php

```
<body>

<div id="languages">
<a href="index.php?//?????????//"><img src="images/en.png" /></a>
<a href="index.php?//?????????//"><img src="images/pl.png" /></a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="tresc">
        <?php if($langID == 'Pl'): ?>
        <div class="editable" id="polska">
        <h1>Head</h1>
        <p>first land</p>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="editable" id="angielska">
        <h1>Head</h1>
        <p>second lang</p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

what I should put here to trigger script

```
<div id="languages">
<a href="index.php?//?????????//"><img src="images/en.png" /></a>
<a href="index.php?//?????????//"><img src="images/pl.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: A *good looking* PHP script? Well, it's on the inside that counts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="index.php?lang=En"><img src="images/en.png" /></a>
<a href="index.php?lang=Pl"><img src="images/pl.png" /></a>
```

Comment: "- How to know that Dan Grossman has returned to SO?" "- You're no longer able to make fast answers first" ;-)

Comment: http://gidzior.net/drewniana9/index.php  this is my page, script is working only in one way

Comment: You need to be consistent with capitalization. "pl", "Pl" and "PL" are not the same word.

Answer (score 0):

And, for the sake of all that is holy, please check that the vale of $_GET['lang'] is acceptable before putting it in the cookie:

```
if (in_array($_GET['lang'], array('pl','en','fr')) {
    $langID = $_GET['lang'];
} else {
    // throw an error
}
```

If you don't do this your script will not be secure.